# Obtener un total mediante una sola query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo las siguientes tablas donde estoy realizando un inventario, pero aparte tengo una tabla de reserva.

```
 Tabla Inventario
 -------------------
| pieza  |cantidad |
|--------|---------| 
| pieza1 |100      |
| pieza2 |20       |
| pieza3 |30       |
| pieza4 |10       |
| pieza5 |30       |
|--------|---------|


 Tabla Reserva
 -------------------
| pieza  |cantidad |
|--------|---------| 
| pieza1 |10       |
| pieza1 |20       |
| pieza2 |10       |
| pieza2 |5        |
| pieza5 |30       |
|--------|---------|
```

Tengo la siguiente query donde realizo una consulta si la pieza tiene reserva.

```
 $result_reserva = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM Inv_Reserva
      where CodPza='$codpza'");
      if($res_reserva=$result_reserva->fetch_assoc())
      {
        $reserva="SI";
        $query   = "SELECT SUM(Cantidad) FROM Inv_Reserva where CodPza='$codpza' ";
        $result  = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
        $row     = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        $reservatotal = $row[0];

        $query2       = "SELECT Cantidad FROM Inv_Inventario where CodPza='$codpza'";
        $result2      = mysqli_query($conexion, $query2);
        $roww         = mysqli_fetch_row($result2);
        $invTotal = $roww[0];

        $total = $reservaTotal-$invTotal;
      }
      else{
        $reserva="NO";
      }
```

Si me encuentra me gustaria realizar una query donde me obtenga el inventario disponible visible `(Cantidad Inventario - Cantidad Reserva)`.

Tengo la siguiente query para obtener la suma total de las reservas.

```
//Query Reserva total
SELECT SUM(Cantidad) FROM `Inv_Reserva` WHERE CodPza='$pieza' ;
 //Query Inventario 
SELECT Cantidad FROM Inv_Inventario WHERE CodPza='$pieza';
```

Pero me gustaria poder realizar la suma y resta en una sola query. Espero haberme explicado bien. Saludos!

Comment: cual es el query que te obtiene la cantidad de inventario?

Comment: @gbianchi la agrego

Answer (score 1):

Y por qué no lo calculas directamente con php?
Haces una query para el valor total, otra para la reserva y desde php una nueva variable con la resta:

```
$cantidad=0;
$reserva=0;

$sql="SELECT cantidad FROM Inv_Inventario where CodPza='".$codpza."'";
$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
if($resultado->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
       $cantidad=$row["cantidad"];
    }
}

$sql="SELECT cantidad FROM Inv_Reserva where CodPza='".$codpza."'";
$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
if($resultado->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
       $reserva=$row["cantidad"];
    }
}
$total = $cantidad - $reserva;
```

Con esto sacarías una de las variables, repites el proceso para la otra y luego creas una variable nueva y haces la resta.

Creo que se entiende. Si no, me dices.

Comment: Tengo algo asi yo en mi codigo, pero me gustaria mejorarlo y hacerlo en una pura query. Agregare mi codigo

Comment: Creo que es mucho comerse la cabeza para algo que tampoco es crucial... Si tienes algo así, está bien. No hace falta que te vuelvas loco con ello. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Podrias intentar hacer un join de las dos tablas ya que el codPieza es el mismo en ambas .
Algo así:

```
 select sum(i.cantidad) - r.cantidad as total from inventario i join reservas r on i.codPieza = r.codPieza
```

cuando hacemos un join tenemos todos los registros de las dos tablas, en este caso lo que quieres es restar sus valores, pero en una consulta por ello tienes que unir el valor de las dos tablas en una consulta, y una vez que tienes se valor pues restarlo

pd: el "as total" puedes cambiarlo, en sql puedes utilizar "as" para cambiar el nombre(solo visualmente) de la columna, por ejemplo podrías poner as resta 
Espero que te sirva

Answer (score 1):

para esto podrías utilizar las 2 queries que ya tienes construidas y agregarlas dentro de un unico SELECT de esta manera.

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT Cantidad FROM Inv_Inventario WHERE CodPza='$pieza') - (SELECT SUM(Cantidad) FROM `Inv_Reserva` WHERE CodPza='$pieza') as total_inventario;
```

De esta manera estarás restando el total de reservas al total de inventario obteniendo la cantidad de inventario disponible.

Para realizar esto es importante que cada una de tus queries obtengan como resultado 1 sola columna con un valor numerico que en este caso seria la cantidad de inventario y la suma total de las reservas de una pieza.

Espero haberte ayudado, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

INTENTA CON

```
select pieza, 
       sum(cantidad - cantidad_reserva) resta,
       sum(cantidad + cantidad_reserva) suma
from ( ---calculas la suma de reservas por pieza
select A.cantidad,
       A.pieza,
      (select NVL(sum(cantidad),0) from Inv_Reserva where pieza =A.pieza) AS cantidad_reserva
from Inv_Inventario A)
group by pieza
```

Comment: por favor considera añadir una explicación a tu código, pues respuestas que son solo código se consideran de baja calidad, además esta respuesta debe ser comprensible para todos los usuarios y usuarios que la consulten después

Comment: puede probar consultar por partes para ver si es lo que estabas buscando, ahi  te muestra la resta inventario - reserva y tambien la suma inventario + reserva

Comment: dale editar y añade tu explicación a tu respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer un select con un left join entre las 2 tablas de la siguente forma:

```sql
 SELECT i.id, MAX(i.cant) cantidad ,
        IFNULL(SUM(r.cant),0) reservado,
        MAX(i.cant)- IFNULL(SUM(r.cant),0) disponible
 FROM inventario i
      LEFT JOIN reserva r ON i.id=r.id
 GROUP BY i.id
```